# SWTBot Jenkins issue

Tags: jenkins, swtbot

I have a piece of SWTBot code that runs perfectly well when started on my machine but fails when run by Jenkins:

```
...
SWTBotTreeItemExtension readSchemaProperty = 
  new SWTBotTreeItemExtension(readProperties.getTreeItem("Schema").widget, readProperties.widget);
readSchemaProperty.click(1);
readSchemaProperty.click(1);
readSchemaProperty.pressShortcut(Keystrokes.DOWN);
...
```

(The SWTBotTreeItemExtension is a custom class for clicking in table widgets like the one used in the Properties view; cf. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/153600/)

The test is executed by Tycho. There are no errors when it is started by Jenkins but the clicks and keystrokes don't have any effect. When I start it manually on the command line, everything works fine.

I read somewhere that there are "focus issues" when using SWTBot with Jenkins and Jenkins is installed as a service on Windows, but I don't understand how this can cause that kind of problem while leaving the rest of my tests unharmed. 
All constructive comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins runs as Windows service it cannot interact with the Bot.
http://habibbabbles.blogspot.com/2013/06/running-ui-tests-from-jenkins.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't validate your answer as I do no longer have access to the environment I was working on at that time. I should've deleted the question. I remember testing it with Jenkins NOT run as a service back then but I don't remember the outcome of my tests. sry again.